# Improving word match (look ahead?) algorithm performance

Tags: algorithm, parsing

I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of the Text annotation at http://mandarinspot.com/annotate and I have a solution but my effort falls way short in terms of speed. I did look at string search algorithms and the techniques vary for each application, so I'm looking for some pointers here.

This page takes a chunk of Chinese and adds Pinyin pronunciation on top, and a definition tooltip. The reasons I want to reproduce this page is: 1. I like using a different phonetic system called Gwoyeu Romatzyh, and 2. for re-learning programming.

I'll try to describe what I'm doing, replacing the underlying Chinese language with English. Let's say that for a given string, "Gary ate a grape and a grapefruit" the program must output a definition for each word, like "[proper name] [to ingest food] [fruit grows in clusters] [large citrus fruit]". Now, since 'grape' and 'grapefruit' begin the same, the program needs to tell them apart (In Chinese, there are no spaces so splitting the string is not an option, so really I would have to parse "Garyateagrapeandagrapefruit" and have it "look ahead" when parsing "grapefruit").

My data structure is a tree structure where each node holds a single Chinese character and a parent ID. If that character is part of a phrase, parent tells me what the previous character of the phrase was.

Example: if "ABC" is a Chinese word, A could have ID of 1, and no parent ID, B: ID=2 and parent=1, and C: ID=3, parent=2. For "ABD", D would have ID=4 and parent=2 (B). Each node also has a 'definition' array which points to a separate array holding the English definition for that character or word. The 'definition' would be blank if the node is not the final one for a word.

To parse a string,

1. Hold the current character (curChar), and the character following it (nextChar), to two variables.
2. Search for a node where nextChar matches the node's character and this node has curChar as a parent. If this is true, I figure that I have a two or more-character long word. If it is false, I conclude that there is no relationship between curChar and nextChar, and output whatever I had up to curChar.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: So you have the algorithm, which worked well in one language but was slow in another?

Comment: It's slow in both. I thought rewriting in PHP+MySQL would make it faster but it is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aho-Corasick in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) will give you a fast algorithm that finds all the words from a dictionary when they appear in a stream. Given that, you could pick longest alternatives, as you have been doing, or use dynamic programming to find a path through the words found that accounts for all the characters in the stream.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Some preliminary tests show that it's many times faster than what I had written.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion - How about using a hash table instead of a tree ? It would increase the lookup efficiency if you use it combined with a rolling hash ( like the one used in the Rabin-Karp string seach algorithm ), so that hash computation takes O(1) per sub-string, and look-up takes average case O(1).

Comment: Thank you for answering! After reading about the common applications of Rabin-Karp, it seems that it's best used for locating a string inside a larger text so it's not really the best fit for my problem. The Rabin-Karp typical usage assumes you already know what you are looking for, but in my case, I need to find out what the next longest word is in the text, and continue "matching" everything in the text to its phonetic value.